# How can I prevent extra quotations being inserted into MySQLdb statement from Python?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have a series of SQL select statements that I need to run from a Python script using MySQLdb. One of the variables I would like to pass to the select statements is called `unit_ids`. I've tried treating `unit_ids` as a string as well as a tuple of strings. Initially, backslashes were being inserted into the string. After looking around online, I've been able to avoid the backslashes, but now extra quotation marks are being inserted instead. Here is my current code:

```
connection = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'root', '*****', 'test')
cur = connection.cursor

unit_ids = ('0A1', '0A2', '0A3', '0A4')
attr = 'sample'

cur.execute("""SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE attribute = %s AND unit_id IN %r""", (a, tuple(unit_ids)))
```

Using `cur._last_executed`, I can see that the actual SQL statement that was performed was:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE attribute = 'sample' AND unit_id IN ("'0A1'", "'0A2'", "'0A3'", "'0A4'")
```

Any ideas on what I need to change in order to have `('0A1', '0A2', '0A3', '0A4')` remain unchanged in the SQL statement?

UPDATE: Here's the exact output I get even when using `%s`:

```
>>> cn = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'root', '***', '***')
>>> c = cn.cursor()
>>> unit_ids = ('0A1', '0A2', '0A3', '0A4')
>>> a = 'foo'
>>> c.execute("""select count(*) from model_test where attribute = %s and unit_id in %s""", (a, unit_ids))
1L
>>> print(c._last_executed)
select count(*) from model_test where attribute = 'foo' and unit_id in ("'0A1'", "'0A2'", "'0A3'", "'0A4'")
```

At this point, I think I may just need to create separate variables for each element of `unit_ids` (eg `unit_id1 = '0A1'`). I'm using Python 2.7.9 and MySQL Server 5.6, by the way.

UPDATE 2: @thebjorn solved it: my version of MySQLdb was outdated. After upgrading, there were no more extra quotation marks being inserted into the SQL statement.

Comment: Maybe try: `unit_ids = '("0A1", "0A2", "0A3", "0A4")'`

Comment: This is funny. `print("""SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE attribute = %s AND unit_id IN %r""", (a, tuple(unit_ids)))` works for me, and `cur.execute` should conform to the same syntax.

Comment: or add the trailing comma and use only unit_ids in the execute string rather than tuple(unit_ids)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any magic, just do it the regular mysql way:

```
connection = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'root', '*****', 'test')
cur = connection.cursor()

unit_ids = ('0A1', '0A2', '0A3', '0A4')
attr = 'sample'

cur.execute("""SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE attribute = %s AND unit_id IN %s""", (a, unit_ids))
```

the only wrinkle I can see is if `a` was not included and `unit_ids` only had one item, then the tuple syntax could trip you up.  If you make `unit_ids` into a list then the syntax wouldn't be quite as awkward:

```
unit_ids = ('0A1',)
cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE unit_id IN %s", (unit_ids,))
```

which when inlined becomes:

```
cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE unit_id IN %s", (('0A1',),))
```

vs. using lists (one parameter, that parameter is a one item list):

```
cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE unit_id IN %s", [['0A1']])
```

You can use `%s` for all mysql parameters (a few others can be used too, but not `%r` -- this isn't string interpolation).

**Update:** you must be doing *something* differently from me.. here is the output of cursor._last_executed

```
>>> cn = MySQLdb.connect('server', 'user', 'password', 'database')
>>> c = cn.cursor()
>>> unit_ids = ('0A1', '0A2', '0A3', '0A4')
>>> c.execute("select count(*) from foo where id in %s", (unit_ids,))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ...
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'djangodevelop.foo' doesn't exist")
>>> c._last_executed
"select count(*) from foo where id in ('0A1','0A2','0A3','0A4')"
>>>
```

Comment: If I run the code in your first code block and then add the line `print(cur._last_executed)` to show the exact SQL statement sent to the database, I still see ...`AND unit_id IN ("'0A'", "'0A2'", "'0A3'", "'0A4'")`. The code works, in that it doesn't throw an error, but the additional quotations around each element in `unit_ids` causes the select statement to be incorrect.

Comment: I'm not getting the extra quotes (see updated answer).  Did you remember to change your `%r` to `%s`?

Comment: @zkstine you are using wrong parameter `%r`. Do not use that when building queries. Check my answer.

Comment: @thebjorn: see my updated question. I'm using %s and still ending up with extra quotations around each element of `unit_ids`.

Comment: @zkstine What does `MySQLdb.__version__` give you?

Comment: Perhaps you'll need to upgrade..?  (I'm at 1.3.3)

Comment: @thebjorn That was it! After upgrading MySQLdb, there are no more extra quotations. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `%r` in `unit_id IN %r`. Python-Mysql database API only supports `%s` as place holder when building SQL queries.

[From the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html)

> In the preceding example, we store the SELECT statement in the variable query. Note that we are using unquoted %s-markers where dates should have been. Connector/Python converts hire_start and hire_end from **Python types to a data type that MySQL understands and adds the required quotes**. In this case, it replaces the first %s with '1999-01-01', and the second with '1999-12-31'.

You can see similar warning and usage in [Python-MySql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-reference.html).

```
cur.execute("""
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE attribute = %s AND unit_id IN %s
""", (a, ('0A1', '0A2', '0A3', '0A4')))
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer @FallenAngel. @thebjorn has already pointed out that I need to use `%s` instead of `%r`. Now I just want to pass the whole variable `unit_ids` to the SQL statement instead of each element explicitly, but when I do that, extra quotations are inserted around each element.